# Determine the integral $f(x,y,z)=y$ bounded by the region $x=0,y=0,z=0$ and $2x+2y+z=4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I somewhat drew a picture and this looks to be a pyramid type shape and so using the lower bound $z=0$ and the upper bound $4-2x-2y=z$. Then just looking at the $xy-plane$ if I want to integrate y first I believe my bounds are $0$ and the line $y=-x$. Then integrating $x$ last my bounds are $0,2$ so I get:

$\int\int_D\int_0^{4-2x-2y} y dzdA=\int_0^2\int_0^{-x}\int_0^{4-2x-2y} y dzdydx$

Evaluating this I found the integral to be 4.

Does this seem correct? The main thing I'm unsure of is the bounds for $y$.

Comment: I don't see the line $\;y=-x\;$ on the plane $\;z=0\;$ , but rather the line $\;y=2-x\;$

Comment: No you are right I see I screwed that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the plane $\;z=0\;$ , the given plane projects as $\;2x+2y=4\implies y=2-x\;$
 , so

$$\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}\int_0^{4-2x-2y}y\,dz\,dy\,dx=\int_0^2dx\int_0^{2-x}y(4-2x-2y)\,dy=$$

$$=\int_0^2\left((2-x)y^2-\frac23y^3\right)_0^{2-x}dx=\int_0^2\left[(2-x)^3-\frac23(2-x)^3\right]dx=$$

$$=\frac13\int_0^2(2-x)^3dx=\left.-\frac1{12}(2-x)^4\right|_0^2=-\frac1{12}\left(0^4-2^4\right)=\frac43$$